# I cannot connect my database with my javafx app listview

Tags: java, mysql, database, listview, javafx

I'm in need of help. I'm making a simple app in javafx, the app has to connect with a database and return some data that I will show on a listview right as the app loads.

The thing is, that I can't find the reason why errors come back to me saying that the list in null.

My controller:

```
public void cargarDatos(){

        //MythosList.getItems().clear();

        try {

            //Creamos el array donde guardar los datos
            List<Mytho> mythos = mythosDAO.obtenerMythos();

            System.out.println("Número de elementos en la lista: " + mythos.size()); //This retrieves 3, which is the amount of lines I have in my database
            MythosList.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(mythos)); //This is the line that provokes the error
            System.out.println("Beep"); //It doesn't reach this line
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            AlertTemp.mostrarError("Error cargando los datos de la aplicación");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I have declared the listview as: `@FXML private ListView<Mytho> MythosList;`

And my main app:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        AppCtrl controller = new AppCtrl();

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

        //Con esto se deberian cargar los datos de la BBDD,
        //pero dice que es NULL
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
        System.out.println("Beep");
        controller.cargarDatos(); //Again, this is the line that provokes errors
        System.out.println("Beep"); //But it reaches here!!


        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
```

And the error is this one:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ListView.setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)" because "this.MythosList" is null`

I'm out of ideas, and the connection is okay, so it can't be that. The size of the array is the one it has to be, so I don't understand why in the last moment it breaks.

Comment: The typo in the @FXML statement is only here, in the question, and not in your code?

Comment: `AppCtrl controller = fxmlLoader.getController()`after  `fxmlLoader.load()` if you want the FXML properties to load

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to *both* of your catch blocks.  If something went wrong, you do want to know exactly what it was and where it occurred, right?

Comment: Why are you even calling `controller.cargarDatos();` in the `Main`? Should you be using the `Controller's` `initialize` method?

Comment: Off-topic: please use proper naming conventions when posting code.

Answer (score 3):

`@FXML`-injected fields will be initialized to corresponding elements in the FXML file during the call to `FXMLLoader.load()`. Since you call

```
fxmlLoader.load()
```

*before* you call `fxmlLoader.setController(controller)`, at the time you call `load()` there is no controller, and so no initialization of the fields can be done.

Reverse the order of the calls:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    AppCtrl controller = new AppCtrl();

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("main.fxml"));

    fxmlLoader.setController(controller);

    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

    //Con esto se deberian cargar los datos de la BBDD,
    //pero dice que es NULL
    System.out.println("Beep");
    controller.cargarDatos(); //Again, this is the line that provokes errors
    System.out.println("Beep"); //But it reaches here!!


    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

Assuming everything else (in code you haven't posted) is correct, then this should now mean that `MythosList` is no longer null.